# Is there code in AS3 save image in desktop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Are there any code or tutorial in AS3 that could save into Jpeg format into a specific file location. I have found many articles here in stackoverflow, but it is using php.
Somehow, I have this one: http://www.permadi.com/blog/2011/02/flash-as3-saving-image-to-disk/. I can't follow the codes. I only understand very basic AS3.
Please help, any codes or useful links will be helpful.

Comment: I don't quite understand, the code in your link does do what you need, it prompts the user to select a location then saves the file without php.

Comment: Yes, it does, but it has too many codes. I can't trace which code/s could function to render it in jpeg. Is there any much more simple example?

Comment: I'm sorry but you would need to do some googling for this, Stackoverflow is used to help you with code you are writing and any issues you have with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to find method to save BitmapData to image Bytes , check for PNGEncoder or JPEGEncoder .

Than use following code in AIR application:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = YourImageBytes;
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("fileName.ext");          
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(file , FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(bytes)
fs.close();
```

It will save img on desktop .

If You developing FlashPlayer app , only user can choose file destination using browse box in FileReference .